# jQuery code that registers click events and on each 3rd event the user will be redirected to a custom url

Tags: jquery

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sexywebteacher/TLkPB/1/) with the following situation and I'd like an idea on how to implement it with jQuery.

I have several divs like so:

```
<div class="mydiv"><a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a></div>

<div class="mydiv"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo.com</a></div>

<div class="mydiv"><a href="http://www.baidu.com">baidu.com</a></div>
```

The list goes on (O have about 20 divs).

1. When the user clicks on the first div (1st event), he will go to the
   page of that link (in my case google.com);
2. When the user clicks on the second div (2nd event), he will go to the page of that link (yahoo.com);
3. When the user clicks on the third div (3rd event), he will go to a
   CUSTOM URL and not baidu.com;
4. But if the user clicks on the third div again (4th event), he will go to baidu.com

**To summarize, I need an idea for a jQuery code that registers click events and on each 3rd event the user will be redirected to a custom url.**

My first taught is to use toggle, but I'm not sure it can be implemented.

Comment: open the links in new tabs, using jquery, and keep a counter.

Comment: Either I miss something or there is only one click on the page as you leave it.

Comment: The links open in new tab, I should have mentioned that. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution maintains a counter even if you leave the page :

```
$(function(){
    var nbc = localStorage['nbc']||0;
    $('a').click(function(){
        localStorage['nbc'] = ++nbc;
        if (nbc%3==0) {
           document.location = "yourUrl";
           return false; // in case the link opens in another page
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT, some answers to questions in comment :**

To have an html link open in a new tab, do it like this :

```
<a href=... target=_blank>text</a>
```

To open programatically in a new tab (or window, it's browser and preferences dependent), use

```
window.open("yourUrl");
```

To have the opener window focus after the opening can only be made if you control the new page and if it's from the same origin. In this case only you may have this in the new page :

```
window.opener.focus();
```

Comment: Ty very much for answering. I approved heartcode's answer because it was the first one who answered. So I wanted to be fair. Hope you understand.

Comment: Upon implementation I have decided your answer was the best and accepted it accordingly. If you look again at this question, do you have any idea on how to make the new location open into a new tab and make the browser focus on the old one (not changing from the old to the new tab)? Ty

Comment: I like this solution (better than mine), it looks slicker :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var counter = 0;
  $('.mydiv a').on('click', function(event){
    counter = counter < 3 ? counter + 1 : 0;

    if (counter == 3) {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    }
  });
});
```

The above code should redirect the user to your custom URL on the time they click. Obviously you can set the limit of the clicks just as well as the custom URL.

Please be careful with hijacking your user's clicks :)

---

### EDIT

Check out the code in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/robertp/GHnvd/3/

Comment: I will be careful :) cross my heart. It's about google and it's updates, webmasters seem to start exchanging traffic the old fashioned way, not relying that much on search engines who, behind their surfer care mask, knowingly make poor results in order to enhance the number of ads webmasters put on google.

Comment: Ty for answering, you were a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the number of clicks in memory using jQuery's [**data()**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and re-set it every 3 clicks when going to your custom link if that is what you need like this:

```
$document = $(document);
$document.data("linksClicked", 0);

$(".mydiv a").on("click", function() {
    var clicks = $document.data("linksClicked");

    clicks += 1;

    if (clicks === 3) {
        // go to special link
        clicks = 0;
        $document.data("linksClicked", clicks);
        return false;
    }

    $document.data("linksClicked", clicks);
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TLkPB/8/) - All but every 3rd click go to assigned link

If you don't want to re-set the counter you can simply stop incrementing it after the third like this:

```
$document = $(document);
$document.data("linksClicked", 0);

$(".mydiv a").on("click", function() {
    var clicks = $document.data("linksClicked");

    if (clicks < 3) {
        clicks += 1;

        if (clicks === 3) {
            // go to special link
            $document.data("linksClicked", clicks);
            return false;
        }

        $document.data("linksClicked", clicks);
    }
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TLkPB/9/) - All but 3rd click go to assigned link

Comment: Tested it, ty very much for respondig. Just made a fiddle and it seemed to work. When I asked the Q I expected an idea on how to make it; I did not expect such great guys willing to help this much. I am impressed :)

Comment: Though I got a browser message before the redirect, need to test some more.

Comment: @webmasters: I only used the HTML you provided, but off course if you have a fiddle you have issues with post the link and I'm sure we figure it out.

Comment: Ty very much for answering. I approved heartcode's answer because it was the first one who answered. So I wanted to be fair. Hope you understand. I have plus one'd yours.

Comment: @webmaster: no worries. You accept the answer which helped you solve your problem and if more than one did so, accepting the first one posted which helped solve the problem is what I do myself as well. Glad you got it sorted, that's the main thing :)